# how to set !important on a multi value css transform?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I want to undo older css `transform` applied to an element and set new rule. 
In css we regularly use `!important` in such cases to override the higher priority rule, but it looks like `!important` is not taking effect on a transform property:

```css
.mk-flipbox-front {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

I want to override this to:

```css
.mk-flipbox-front {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

but when I use `!important` like this:

```css
transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(0deg) !important;
```

It breaks and will not work.

Any chance we can use `!important` on a multiple value `transform`?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to override the values for the properties?
[https://jsfiddle.net/kz0dnyzf/](https://jsfiddle.net/kz0dnyzf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question

> Any chance we can use !important on a multiple value transform?

You can use `!important` the way you are using like in any other property

If your `!important` rule is not working is  because of [**CSS specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and/or **[CSS inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance)**

---

**Don't use `!important`**

Instead be more specific, and use a parent selector (or even a sibling selector) to override it

something like this:

```css
.mk-flipbox-front {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.parent .mk-flipbox-front {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="mk-flipbox-front">test</div>
</div>
```